# How to properly override a function like org-babel-ruby-evaluate

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to "override" a function

```
(defun org-babel-ruby-evaluate (buffer body &optional result-type)
```

I think it came with org mode, which came with prelude.

As a first step, I paste this unmodified version (found via google)
in to *Scratch* and eval-buffer

```
(defun org-babel-ruby-evaluate (buffer body &optional result-type)
  "Pass BODY to the Ruby process in BUFFER.  If RESULT-TYPE equals
'output then return a list of the outputs of the statements in
BODY, if RESULT-TYPE equals 'value then return the value of the
last statement in BODY."
  (if (not session)
      ;; external process evaluation
      (save-window-excursion
        (case result-type
          (output
           (with-temp-buffer
             (insert body)
             ;; (message "buffer=%s" (buffer-string)) ;; debugging
             (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "ruby" 'replace)
             (buffer-string)))
          (value
           (let ((tmp-file (make-temp-file "ruby-functional-results")))
             (with-temp-buffer
               (insert (format org-babel-ruby-wrapper-method body tmp-file))
               ;; (message "buffer=%s" (buffer-string)) ;; debugging
               (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "ruby"))
             (with-temp-buffer (insert-file-contents tmp-file) (buffer-string))))))
    ;; comint session evaluation
    (message "session evaluation")
    (let* ((full-body (mapconcat #'org-babel-chomp
                                 (list body org-babel-ruby-last-value-eval org-babel-ruby-eoe-indicator) "\n"))
           (raw (org-babel-comint-with-output buffer org-babel-ruby-eoe-indicator t
                  (insert full-body) (comint-send-input nil t)))
           (results (cdr (member org-babel-ruby-eoe-indicator
                                 (reverse (mapcar #'org-babel-ruby-read-string
                                                  (mapcar #'org-babel-trim raw)))))))
      (case result-type
        (output (mapconcat #'identity (reverse (cdr results)) "\n"))
        (value (car results))))))
```

But I don't think it worked for me, I got

Eager macro-expansion failure: (wrong-type-argument listp buffer)

in minibufffer.

Comment: You should state what you actually want to do. This looks very much like an [XY-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Normally one uses [hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) and [advices](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) to modify the behavior of functions pre-defined in packages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a emacs feature called M-x find-function
which gave me the correct prototype of the function.

That worked. MY guess is that the function I found on the
web was outdated, so it didn't fit in well with the rest of the system.